# This expression is not callable. Zustand & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

Error: This expression is not  callable. No constituent of type 'callStatusType' is callable.
Code:

```
 import { create } from "zustand";
type callStatusType = "Calling" | "Answered" | "Declined";
interface IuseCallStatus {
  callStatus: callStatusType;
  setCallStatus: (status: callStatusType) => void;
}
export const useCallStatus = create<IuseCallStatus>((set) => ({
  callStatus: "Declined",
  setCallStatus: (status) => {
    set({
      callStatus: status,
    });
  },
}));
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How do you call it? Hope this helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-lamport-uiq9nu

Comment: Thank you! Error was in call...